# How to create a deeply nested data model that supports deep copying?

Tags: java, kotlin, functional-programming, deep-copy

I'm porting a 2D graphics engine from Swift to Kotlin. Large parts of the data model are nested structs in Swift. As a simple example:

```
struct Point {
  var x: Float
  var y: Float
}

struct Size {
  var width: Float
  var height: Float
}

struct Rect {
  var origin: Point
  var size: Size
}
```

Many model structures are deeply nested, with way more levels than here. Also, as we use `struct`s instead of `class`es for most types, which are value typed in Swift, we can easily use pure functions for 2D operations, like in this small, contrived example:

```
func translate(rect1: Rect, dx: Float) -> Rect {
  var rect2 = rect1 // Creates a mutable deep copy
  rect2.origin.x += dx
  return rect2
}
```

This approach gives us a high performance, no memory handling issues (everything lives on the stack), and great testability. As the `struct`s are value typed, we cannot accidentally create shallow copies and modify the wrong objects.

What's the idiomatic way to create such a model in Kotlin?

It looks like Kotlin's data classes are a solution, but I don't know how copying deeply nested data classes is usually done. Do you create custom deepCopy() methods everywhere?

Should I be worried about the performance if the call of a copy()/deepCopy() method triggers a torrent of other copy()/deepCopy() calls down the model? (From a C programmer's perspective, I see thousands of small, short lived allocations on the heap)